# C++ CLI handle types

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli

What's the appropriate way to get the `non-handle` type in the following code:

```
template <typename Type> ref class SuperClass
{
public:
    void Method()
    {
        Type x = gcnew ???? (...);
        // I want it to be instantiated into 'String^ x = gcnew String(...).
        // Is there a way to "dereference" the handle type in C++ \ CLI ?
    }
};

SuperClass<String^> superClass;
superClass.Method(); // <---- Won't compile
```

Also, the usage of handle type as a template parameter **is mandatory** (this is a part of bigger example, where I can't simply change the template type to `String` instead of `String^`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcnew always returns a handle (^).
So here is something you can try. Not sure if it really meets your needs -

<strike>template  ref class SuperClass
    {
    public:
        void Method()
        {
                Type^ x = gcnew Type("Hello");
        }
    };</strike>

```
SuperClass<String> superClass;
superClass.Method();
```

```
template <typename Type> ref class SuperClass
{
public:
    void Method()
    {
    Type x = "Hello";
    }
};

SuperClass<String^> superClass;
superClass.Method();
```

Comment: My last comment actually tells that I can't avoid passing the **handle type** as the template parameter. However, thank you :)

Comment: It didn't :) However, you pushed me towards the correct solution for my case, thank's again.

Comment: Hi @Yippie-Ki-Yay.  What was the solution you came up with?  I have a similar problem. See also https://xkcd.com/979/